# Spring Get endpoint returning 406 when special character is in pathVariable

Tags: regex, spring-boot, encoding, character-encoding, endpoint

I have endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/f{url:.*}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> read(@PathVariable("url") String url) {
...
}
```

When i try to `get` with:

```
https://baseUrl/f2Fretail
```

Then i get `200`

But when I try:

```
https://baseUrl/f%2Fretail
```

I get `406`.

I changed security to use:

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedPercent(true);
    firewall.setAllowBackSlash(true);
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
    return firewall;
}
```

I want to get always `200` here and that Spring process `%` in `{url}` section or another characters as regular one and store it in `url` variable.

Cause of `contract` i have to use `PathVariable` here.

When i removed headers i get:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-13T11:04:48.448+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "favbb/bbb"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL not broken due that encoding. If broken you will get `bad request  - 400` or `not found - 404`.

406 - something wrong with your header. Add accept all in controller level.

Issue not with your encoding. Not able to return data. Your return some `byte[]` that not acceptable from front end.

Try to return some string instead of byte check whether your API working or not.

Comment: yes - i know - cause that String contains special characters and i want to stop Spring from parsing it. This is not the answer to the question. I want `Spring` to accept whole `String` as in regex `.*` every sign after character `f` from the url address. I know that `path variable` is not reccommend but that is mandatory cause of external `contract`.

Comment: I also had the same problems

Comment: For exmple think like if you want pass any empty value in path variable then how you send

Comment: I that case I used %20

Comment: That not work at postman level but it worked when do the curls

Comment: I do not need empty character here. I want to make for example `https://baseUrl/f%2Fretail` get parsed correctly using `path variable`. So the String should have `%2Fretail` as `value`.

Comment: If you have any additional characters like #,/ then path variable not recommended.

Comment: As i stated before:
I know that path variable is not recommended but that is mandatory cause of external `contract` in my case. This is `mock` simulating that contract.

Comment: You can encode those additional characters not support across all browser.. some will be decoded when received at controller.

Comment: please edit your answer and provide some code cause I am not sure about what changes you are implying. Also this code is pure `backend` do not worry about `browser`.

Comment: Check now ... Encoding will work you have problem in the header.

Comment: Yes, I have also `Content-Type` as `application/json` and `Accept` `application/pdf` if you turn these off you will get 404 and 400 or `500`.
You can check it yourself with the code I provided and using postman. Still - how to not get the `404` and `400` or `500` - I want answer to that. `byte[]` that I return does not make a difference - try to return empty new array of bytes. I get `200` when `url` is valid with byte array.

Comment: With these headers turned off I get:
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-13T11:04:48.448+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/f/avbb/bbb"
}

What i want is to not proccess this second slash but to store it as value in String.

Comment: @GetMapping(path ={ "/test/{id}/{d}","/test/{id}"})

Comment: public ResponseEntity<Byte[]> findAll(@PathVariable("id")  String id, @PathVariable(value = "d", required = false)

Comment: you can use  required = false for second call

Comment: There are many of special characters in here - you are trying to overcome one `single` `/` character.